# how to execute root command inside non-root process running inside docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I have a docker container running which start up few daemon processes post run with normal user (say with non-root privileges) id. The process which was running with normal user has to create some files and directories under /dev inside the container by calling python function which executes `os.system('mkdir -p /dev/some_dir')` calls. However when run, these calls are failing without the directory being created. But I can run those cmds from container bash prompt where my id is `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`.

Even providing sudo before the cmd inside `os.system('sudo mkdir -p /dev/some_dir')` is not working.

Is there any way I can make it work. I can not run the process with root user id due to security implications, but I need to create this directory as well.

thanks for your pointers

Comment: Why not create these files and directories when you build the image, rather than creating them at runtime? Commands in your Dockerfile run as `root`, so you won't have any permission problems. You can probably get `sudo` to work if you provide an appropriate `sudoers` configuration, but if your non-root user can run `sudo` without a password, you might as well just run as `root` instead.

Comment: A more standard approach would be to run a single process per container, and to then have your application built of multiple containers (maybe using a tool like Docker Compose to orchestrate them).  That would relieve your application container of the problem of starting secondary things and avoid this user-ID problem.  Would this restructuring work for you?

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for your reply. I did not mention - in my container multiple processes are managed by docker supervisord. This process just need to create one char device inside /dev during its run time for further processing. It does execute 3/4 linux commands inside os.system() in code. I am not sure whether I should do it in another extra container or process.

Answer (score -1):

You should give /dev directory a permission to write files for your non-root user.

Comment: This is bad security practice in general; in the case of Docker, the contents of `/dev` are fairly managed and this may not be successful.